# jQuery UI draggable class doesn't work if in php include

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

I am creating a notification system that refreshes a php file executing a query to display the notifications., and am making use of jquery ui draggable by adding the .draggable class to divs with success, but whenever the draggable div is included this way, it doesnt know its a draggable. Any thoughts on why its not seeing itself as a draggable?

I tried adding the draggable script and references to nudgecheck (the included php file where draggable is broken) but no luck.

nudgecheck:

```
 <div id='$nudgeid' class='draggable'>
 // mysql query content
 </div>
```

Code to refresh nudgecheck:

```
 <div id="notifications">
 </div
<script>
function showUser() {
var str = "<? echo $salesman;?>";
 xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
       xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("notifications").innerHTML = this.responseText;

        }
        else if (XMLHttpRequest.readyState == 0) {
        // Network error (i.e. connection refused, access denied due to CORS, etc.)
    }
    else {
        // something weird is happening
    }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET","/nudgecheck/?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
 }




setInterval(function () {
  showUser();
}, 3000);

</script>
```

on the page that has #notifications div

```
        $(function() {
$(".draggable").draggable({ 
     revert: true,
     helper: "clone",
     cursorAt: { bottom: 0 },
     revertDuration: 1000,
     cursorAt: {
        bottom: 0,
        right: 0},
});
```

Comment: `'draggable''` has two closing quotes and `echo $salesman` is missing the ending `;`. Is this the real code?

Comment: do you initialize draggable? `$( ".draggable" ).draggable()`

Comment: @FelippeDuarte no it's not i omitted some stuff to make it simpler, the real code does not have double closing quotes, but I am missing the ; but that echo seems to work.

Comment: @ggirodda I edited my post to show my draggable function, i tried placing it in the included php file and in the main file and neither work. But other elements in the main file that have the .draggable class do work.

Comment: I suspect that either the element does not exist or draggable is called too late? Any console errors?